# Understanding C program that checks string for equal occurrences of characters

Tags: arrays, c, string, for-loop

This program is meant to take a string, and return 0 if there is not an equal occurrence of letters within the string, and 1 if there are an equal occurrence of letters. My question is how this program is able to do this? I understand that the first for loop initializes counts as an array of 26 0's, but around the second for loop is where I start to lose understanding. I know the [s[i] - 'a'] is meant to turn characters into indexes, but im not sure of the purpose of the max variable and how the comparisons at the final for loop are able to determine whether a string has equal occurrences or not. Thank you in advance, and I am happy to answer any questions I can!

```
int areEqualOccurrences( char phrase[] )
{
  int counts[26];
  int max;
  int i;
  
  for(i = 0; i < 26; i++){
      counts[i] = 0; }
  
  for(i = 0; i < strlen(phrase); i++){
      counts[phrase[i] - 'a']++;
      max = counts[phrase[i] - 'a'];
     }
  
  for(i = 0; i < 26; i++){
      if (counts[i] != 0 && counts[i] != max)
        return 0;
  }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: This is using a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) and assuming `phrase` contains only lower-case Latin.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this code simply does not do the job. Nothing to understand then. Or maybe I just didn't undertood what it is supposed to do...

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample input and expected output. I'd like to try whether the program does anything similar to the description. You should too.

Comment: Who is the author of the shown code? I think they are trying to trick you into fixing the program to actually do what it is supposed to do.

Comment: I don't know where this code from, but if it's pro, then this code is really badly written ...
You don't need the `max` variable (which is, by the way, poorly named as it doesn't retain the maximum of anything ...), you don't need to call strlen in the for loop and the real problem : you have to check if all char in the string is actually a lowercase letter. What if I send "Hello world" to this function ?

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) for more information on how deleting content works on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The second for loop counts the characters in the array and initialises max to the count value of the last character in the phrase.
Then the third loop checks that all occurrance counts of characters in the whole phrase matches that of the occurrance count of the last character.

```
aabb => 2 times a, 2 times b, max=2 => 1  
aaab => 3 times a, 1 times b, max=1 => 0  
abcd => everything once, max=1 => 1  
abaa => 3 times a, 1 times b, max=3 => 0  
aaabbbcccdddeeefffggggggg => max=6 (number of 'g's) => 0
```

Alternatively, you could initialise max to the first non-0 value in the array inside the third loop, but that requires an additional conditional check there (if(max==0) max=counts[i];) and requires you to initialise max up front (int max=0;)

Comment: `max` could be efficiently set by putting `if (!phase[0]) return 1;` at the start of the function and `int max = counts[phrase[0] - 'a'];` before the final loop.

Comment: I think the compiler will keep max in a register and it's value is assigned as the by-effect of counts['phrase[i]-'a']++ line above it, so optimising that is not worth your trouble. Optimising this function to begin with is not worth your trouble, it is clearly an educational example and not really usable in real world situations.